# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification won't stop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I've got a little problem using UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. After I leave a certain ViewController (the viewWillDisappear: method is called), the device won't stop to send notifications.

This means, after I pushed another ViewController on top of the stack and I rotate the device, the receivedRotate: method of the ViewController here will be called and that I don't want.

I can't find something in the documentation and on other topics in here as well. It would be great if someone could help.

My scenario is the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

     // other things...
}
```

Here the viewWillAppear: method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

And last the viewWillDisappear: method

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `-viewWillDisappear:`, remove the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked with the following solution: I added code to remove the observer in viewWillDisappear: but had to add the observer in viewWillAppear: because the second time the view will appear, the observer won't be added.
But still, I don't understand the sense of beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications and endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications. In my app, both have no effect on the firing of the notifications. The notifications are always fired?!?!

Comment: All kinds of notifications will fire while your app runs, including those for orientation changes. However, unless a class (z.B. a view controller) has registered to listen for those notifications, that class will not "hear" a notification and will not act upon it. It's up to you how you customize the behavior of your classes, in how you specify how they respond to various system-level notifications.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: I don't think you understood schaechtele's comment. The documentation for beginGeneratingDeviceNotifications says no events will be generated about device orientation changes unless you call this method, but I have also observed it generating notifications without calling this method. I guess it's a system wide thing, if any other app has turned on orientation notifications then you will also get them without calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.